# MiKTeX bibtex can not open .bib file Windows 10 machine

Tags: bibtex, errors, miktex2.9

I'm trying to use .bib file with MiKTeX on Windows 10 machine. But I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\****\latex>bibtex kandi
I couldn't open database file kandi.bib
---line 37 of file kandi.aux
 : \bibdata{kandi.bib
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file kandi.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "einstein"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

The previous run of pdflatex completes ok with three duplicate \newcommand definitions not relating to bibliography, but skipping them works, and the rest of the output looks fine. File kandi.bib is located in a the same directory as .tex and .aux files:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\****\latex

09.04.2020  18.58    <DIR>          .
09.04.2020  18.58    <DIR>          ..
09.04.2020  18.58    <DIR>          fresh
09.04.2020  10.12            11 761 HYgradu.cls
09.04.2020  18.58             1 784 kandi.aux
09.04.2020  18.58                52 kandi.bbl
09.04.2020  10.12               823 kandi.bib
09.04.2020  18.58             1 184 kandi.blg
09.04.2020  18.58            44 612 kandi.log
09.04.2020  18.58                92 kandi.nlo
09.04.2020  18.58               569 kandi.out
09.04.2020  18.58           278 168 kandi.pdf
09.04.2020  18.38             4 734 kandi.tex
09.04.2020  18.58               362 kandi.toc
09.04.2020  10.12           184 041 sinetti.png
              12 File(s)        528 182 bytes
```

The .tex file has following bibtex related defenitions:

```
\usepackage[square]{natbib} % For bibliography
---
Einstein is cool \cite{einstein} as f
---
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname} % This lines adds the bibliography to the ToC
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % numbering 
\bibliography{kandi.bib}
```

The .bib file contains just the usual sample data at the moment (Einstein paper and Knuth book and misc entries).

I have tried to run with TeXWorks and TeXMaker in addition of command line. I have also tried both `miktex-bibtex` and `bibtex` variants and both with `--include-directory=C:\Users\****\latex` option and even with elevated priviledges.

MiKTeX version is:

```
C:\Users\****\latex>bibtex -version
MiKTeX-BibTeX 2.9.7388 (0.99d) (MiKTeX 2.9.7380 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1985, 1988, 2010 Oren Patashnik; all rights reserved.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.61.1; using libcurl/7.61.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2.6; using expat_2.2.6
compiled with liblzma version 50020042; using 50020042
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.8.2; using LibreSSL 2.8.2
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.7348; using 4.7348
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 16.7375; using 16.7375
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6882; using 1.6882
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 9.7364; using 9.7364
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.2
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

Any ideas what to try next? Also tried the same files in Overleaf and the bibliography works there. The work will contain some confidential information, so I try to work without cloud services and thus would like to use MiKTeX locally.

Comment: Don't use `\bibliography{kandi.bib}` but only `\bibliography{kandi}`.

Comment: I could have sworn that back in the day that error would have read: `I couldn't open database file kandi.bib.bib` which would have given you a pretty good idea of what went wrong. But apparently it's only `I couldn't open database file kandi.bib` now... `\bibliography` always takes the name of your `.bib` file **without file extension**. So it should be `\bibliography{kandi}`. (You'll often see the incorrect usage `\bibliography{kandi.bib}` because TeX live is more lenient than MikTeX and actually finds the correct file even with this incorrect input.)

Comment: Yeah! That worked. Thank you :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Comment: I can close this tomorrow with my own answer. below based on @moewe's comment. Or if moewe could create a answer from his/her comment, I can close it sooner.
But I just realized that it still does not work in Texmaker for example.

Comment: @BambOo, as I'm new, I'm asking why answer in comments makes a question off-topic? I think it's still a valid error related question.

Comment: The question should be closed if it was solved in the comments and does not require a full answer

Comment: @BambOo I agree with PSm on this. If someone is willing to turn the comment into a full answer, I think adding that would be better than just closing without an answer. Of course YMMV.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Unless I misunderstood largely how this place works, I believe it is a standard procedure on this forum to close a question when it is solved in the comments. I just did this to keep things tidy.

Comment: I closed the question with my own answer now. I agree with you BambOo that questions should be closed if they have an answer, to keep things tidy as you say. Personally I think that providing a proper answer is more productive and more usable as the correct answer is readily available, rather than going through the comments. Question being off-topic is in my mind a question that is asked in a wrong place. I personally still think that this was the right place for the question. And finally I would like to give thanx to @UlrikeFischer who was actually the first to give the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @moewe 's comment.

Bibliography file name should be given without extension:

```
\bibliography{kandi}
```

**EDIT:** This works on command line, but I just realized that it still does not work on Texmaker for example.

Still getting:

```
Citation `einstein' on page 1 undefined

Empty `thebibliography' environment
```

in Texmaker.

Comment: You have to run latex again. Twice.

Comment: I ran Texmaker with Quick build: pdflatex + bib(la)tex + pdflatex (x2) + view pdf.

Comment: Check if your quick build runs biber (which would be wrong) or bibtex.

Comment: I have the option "PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View Pdf" selected on the Quick Build tab in Options -> Configure Texmaker dialog. And in Commands tab Bib(la)tex field and a value "bibtex %" without the parentheses. So in my understanding, it should be running BibTeX correctly and not biber. I don't know any other way to check it.